# Unity beta 5.5 not building?

Tags: android, windows, unity-game-engine, build, beta

I am trying to build my game using Unity Beta 5.5b6 and 5.5b7. When I click build on either standalone or Android, nothing happens - I can select a directory to save the file in, but nothing else happens. No build progress bar appears and no output is generated.

Is this normal for a beta? Does anyone else have this issue?

*This happens with a blank project too, so it's not just my game, and I've tried on multiple computers*

Edit:
No errors are generated. Literally nothing happens.

Comment: Have you checked the forum to see if this is a known issue?

Comment: Leave beta version, why choose 5.5? Forll

Answer (score 0):

I have posted this question in the 5.5b forums, and apparently building issues across 5.5 b1-7 are an known.

Many thanks to Paradox Forge and Tim for their suggestions.